# Unpivot Columns with Most Recent Record

Tags: t-sql

Student Records are updated for subject and update date. Student can be enrolled in one or multiple subjects. I would like to get each student record with most subject update date and status.

```
    CREATE TABLE Student
    (
        StudentID int,
        FirstName varchar(100),
        LastName varchar(100),
        FullAddress varchar(100),
        CityState varchar(100),
        MathStatus varchar(100),
        MUpdateDate datetime2,
        ScienceStatus varchar(100),
        SUpdateDate datetime2,
        EnglishStatus varchar(100),
        EUpdateDate datetime2
    );
```

Desired query output, I am using CTE method but trying to find alternative and better way.

```
SELECT StudentID, FirstName, LastName, FullAddress, CityState, [SubjectStatus], UpdateDate
    FROM Student


    ;WITH orginal AS
    (SELECT * FROM Student)
    ,Math as
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT StudentID, FirstName, LastName, FullAddress, CityState,
        ROW_NUMBER OVER (PARTITION BY StudentID, MathStatus ORDER BY MUpdateDate DESC) as rn
        , _o.MathStatus as SubjectStatus, _o.MupdateDate as UpdateDate
        FROM original as o
        left join orignal as _o on o.StudentID = _o.StudentID
        where _o.MathStatus is not null and _o.MUpdateDate is not null
    )
    ,Science AS
    (
    ...--Same as Math
    )
    ,English AS
    (
    ...--Same As Math
    )
    SELECT * FROM Math WHERE rn = 1 
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM Science WHERE rn = 1
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM English WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Good day @Justin, Your table structure seems very problematic and limited. You should probably re-design your database, with the understanding that your database design should cover future needs and not only your current needs. For example, what if your Student have more then one address? This is VERY common situation, which you don't cover. You should think about the basics of relational database structure (relations between tables). Address for example, should probably be in separate table, to allow you to have a single-to-many relation (as so other information in the table).

Comment: Your request is not clear to me. Please provide sample data (queries to INSERT some rows to the table), and explain what is your expected result according to the sample data - what do you want to get back from that specific sample data. Try to have sample data which cover all scenarios so we will be able to discuss all option and provide a full solution

Answer (score 0):

First: storing data in a denormalized form is not recommended. Some data model redesign might be in order. There are multiple resources about data normalization available on the web, like [this one](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/database-normalization-in-sql-with-examples).

Now then, I made some guesses about how your source table is populated based on the query you wrote. I generated some sample data that could show how the source data is created. Besides that I also reduced the number of columns to reduce my typing efforts. The general approach should still be valid.

**Sample data**

```
create table Student
(
    StudentId int,
    StudentName varchar(15),
    MathStat varchar(5),
    MathDate date,
    ScienceStat varchar(5),
    ScienceDate date
);

insert into Student (StudentID, StudentName, MathStat, MathDate, ScienceStat, ScienceDate) values
(1, 'John Smith',   'A',  '2020-01-01', 'B',  '2020-05-01'),
(1, 'John Smith',   'A',  '2020-01-01', 'B+', '2020-06-01'),  -- B for Science was updated to B+ month later
(2, 'Peter Parker', 'F',  '2020-01-01', 'A',  '2020-05-01'),
(2, 'Peter Parker', 'A+', '2020-03-01', 'A',  '2020-05-01'),  -- Spider-Man would never fail Math, fixed...
(3, 'Tom Holland',  null, null,         'A',  '2020-05-01'),
(3, 'Tom Holland',  'A-', '2020-07-01', 'A',  '2020-05-01');  -- Tom was sick for Math, but got a second chance
```

**Solution**

Your question title already contains the word *unpivot*. That word actually exists in T-SQL as a keyword. You can learn about the `unpivot` keyword in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15#unpivot-example). Your own solution already contains common table expression, these constructions should look familiar.

Steps:

1. `cte_unpivot` = unpivot all rows, create a `Subject` column and place the corresponding values (`SubjectStat`, `Date`) next to it with a `case` expression.
2. `cte_recent` = number the rows to find the most recent row per student and subject.
3. Select only those most recent rows.

This gives:

```
with cte_unpivot as
(
    select  up.StudentId,
            up.StudentName,
            case up.[Subject]
                when 'MathStat' then 'Math'
                when 'ScienceStat' then 'Science'
            end as [Subject],
            up.SubjectStat,
            case up.[Subject]
                when 'MathStat' then up.MathDate
                when 'ScienceStat' then up.ScienceDate
            end as [Date]
    from Student s
    unpivot ([SubjectStat] for [Subject] in ([MathStat], [ScienceStat])) up
),
cte_recent as
(
    select  cu.StudentId, cu.StudentName, cu.[Subject], cu.SubjectStat, cu.[Date],
            row_number() over (partition by cu.StudentId, cu.[Subject] order by cu.[Date] desc) as [RowNum]
    from cte_unpivot cu
)
select cr.StudentId, cr.StudentName, cr.[Subject], cr.SubjectStat, cr.[Date]
from cte_recent cr
where cr.RowNum = 1;
```

**Result**

```
StudentId   StudentName     Subject SubjectStat Date
----------- --------------- ------- ----------- ----------
1           John Smith      Math    A           2020-01-01
1           John Smith      Science B+          2020-06-01
2           Peter Parker    Math    A+          2020-03-01
2           Peter Parker    Science A           2020-05-01
3           Tom Holland     Math    A-          2020-07-01
3           Tom Holland     Science A           2020-05-01
```